# Whether or not SQLException occurs dependent on value we retrieve

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, arraylist

I'm using a method `getTasksDay(LocalDate day)` that returns a `List` with objects from my own class `HomeworkTask` (given below). I get an `SQLException: The database has been closed` on the next database query when one of the `HomeworkTasks` in the list has the value `true` for its done property. However, when all these values are `false`, everything works fine.

I don't know what I should do to fix this, where fix means that it should work fine no matter what the value of the boolean is. Also, could someone explain this behaviour?

**What I've tried**

1. When I don't close the connection nor the statement, there is no `database has been closed` error, so you could say it works. However, this may lead to an exception like `the database has been locked` or something like it, and having more than one open connection to the database isn't a good idea.
2. Have this method return all the homework tasks with the value `false`, and have another method return an `ArrayList` with the boolean values. Then set those boolean values to the values of the `HomeworkTask` done property. This still gives the same problem. Even though changing the value of the booleans to `true` happens entirely outside of a connection to the database, and I don't see how this would influence the database behaviour.
3. Create a different method that returns an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<String>` with the four values `done`, `task`, `label`, `color` as Strings. Then let `getTasksDay(LocalDate day)` call that method and then use those string values to create and return a list of HomeworkTasks. Yet again, same error.

In general it seems strange to me that using the data after you retreive it from the database influences the database behaviour. But maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. Any suggestions for other places to look are welcome.

**Other information**

I'm using IntelliJ with SQLite (Xerial), or jdbc.

The table `tasks` looks like

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY, done BOOLEAN, day DATE, task CHAR(255), label CHAR(10), color CHAR(50), orderInDay INT
```

**getTasksDay method**

```
public List<HomeworkTask> getTasksDay(final LocalDate day) {

        String dayString = day.toString();
        String sql = "SELECT done, task, label, color " + "FROM tasks " + "WHERE day = '"
                + dayString + "' ORDER BY orderInDay";
        List<HomeworkTask> homeworkTasks = new ArrayList<>();

        setConnection();
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                HomeworkTask homeworkTask = new HomeworkTask(
                                resultSet.getBoolean("done"),
                                resultSet.getString("task"),
                                resultSet.getString("label"),
                                resultSet.getString("color"));
                homeworkTasks.add(homeworkTask);
            }
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return homeworkTasks;
    }

private void setConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databasePath);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note: using the following would work fine. (But doesn't use the value from the database...)

```
HomeworkTask homeworkTask = new HomeworkTask(
                                    false,
                                    resultSet.getString("task"),
                                    resultSet.getString("label"),
                                    resultSet.getString("color"));
                    homeworkTasks.add(homeworkTask);
```

**HomeworkTaks.java**

```
class HomeworkTask implements Serializable {

    private boolean done;
    private String text;
    private String label;
    private String color;

    public HomeworkTask(final boolean done, final String text, final String label, final String color) {
        this.done = done;
        this.text = text;
        this.label = label;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean getDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(final boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(final String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(final String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in directly creating object in the following way

```
 HomeworkTask homeworkTask = new HomeworkTask(
                                resultSet.getBoolean("done"),
                                resultSet.getString("task"),
                                resultSet.getString("label"),
                                resultSet.getString("color"));
```

Rather i would prefer doing

```
boolean done = resultSet.getBoolean("done");
String task = resultSet.getString("task");
String label = resultSet.getString("label");
String color = resultSet.getString("color");

HomeworkTask homeworkTask = new HomeworkTask(done,task,label,color);
```

if possible give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, hadn't directly thought of that. However, this still raises the `the database has been closed` error when trying to access the database again...

Comment: do you mean calling "getTasksDay" method for the second time you are observing the exception?

Comment: The exception comes up when another method that gets data from the database is called. This could as well be `getTasksDay`, doesn't make a difference for trying to connect to a closed database I think.

Comment: Is your connection object a singleton object?

Comment: Yes, it is a singleton object. There is some multithreading going on, however.

Comment: if it is a singleton object and you are trying to close it after every retrieval then what you are seeing is expected. if thread one opens connection and tries to retieve the data , mean while thread two uses the connection to perform the action and then closes the connection even before thread1 completes then we will see SQLException: The database has been closed

Comment: That makes sense. I hadn't noticed that. Any idea why this only goes wrong when the boolean is true? We've been using the database like this for a while, and we didn't see this SQLException before... But when should I close the connection, then? Not closing it at all will raise the `SQLException: the database has been locked`,  later on.